# ASP.NET synchronous commands handlers

Tags: c#, architecture, web-services, domain-driven-design, asp.net-mvc

A question about DDD, for validating a Proof Of Concept.

Let's say we have a webpage that triggers a Domain Event. For instance, updating the status of a client after an interaction occurred on that page. From a user perspective, we want the event to be handled immediately, and the page to refreshed in the server response, because the status has a lot of weight on the information that is displayed on the page.

Domain Events are meant to lead to "Eventual Consistency". How do you handle synchronous events in an ASP.NET application ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got a response. I was looking for some kind of "Request/Respond" pattern implementation, that I found.

[Edit for Svick] For instance, the web application should emit a "DoSomething" command and then wait for a "SomethingDone" notification (or a combo of notifications), introducing a timeout. For sagas and more complex workflows, the point is to know what significant (and minimal) notification(s) should be handled/aggregated by the web application to let the user know his request has been handled and is on a good way to completion.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you found? Otherwise, this answer is useless.

Comment: As it has already been downvoted, this answer is useless.